# Uniformity of hash functions

Tags: hash, uniform-distribution

I'm looking for references that discuss and compare the [**uniformity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Uniformity) of well known **hash** functions.

For example:

1. How does the literature analyze/compare uniformity of hash functions? I.e. what methods and aspects of hash functions are relevant when comparing/evaluating their uniformity?
2. How do well-known hash functions compare with each other in terms of uniformity?

Any pointers on this topic would be helpful.